# error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v7.1'

Tags: android, frameworks, xamarin.android

While building the solution , xamarin throws this error.

error XA0000: Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v7.1'.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your version of Xamarin, or the Android SDK to the latest version. Seems that it can't find what version 7.1 is.